# AS3 - Datagramsocket without port

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, networking

I want to make multiplayer game, and I want it to use UDP sockets. Because of that, I want to use DatagramSocket. The problem is that DatagramSocket needs to be bound to a port on both sides. Is there a way to create a server - client program with UDP that does not need the client to portforward? (Like Serversocket and Socket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that **UDP** is connectionless. You send a packet of data to some IP address and hope it knows what to do with it once it gets to the targeted machine. But actually once it's on the machine it has no idea where to go from there, is there an application that's interested in these packets? And this is precisely why you need to specify a port number that is registered to forward packets to specific application on the machine.

Send a packet to myself to the application running on port 7000: **127.0.0.1 : 7000**

Comment: Does the port have to be port-forwarded?

Comment: @ErikW In most cases clients never have to port-forward. However server-side if it's sitting behind a router you will indeed have to port-forward to let the router know which local machine it needs to forward the packets. There's an in-depth write-up on port-forwarding [here](http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for).